# unable to parse jsonarray of jsonarray inside object using retrofit?

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I am trying to parse the `JSON array` `payment_details` inside the data list of objects.

Here I had parsed the data array successfully called inside recycler view but I am unable to call `payment_details` array.

**Adapter.class**

```
public class InProgress_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InProgress_Adapter.InProgressViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Data_Inprogress> modelRecyclerArrayList;
    Context ctx;

    public InProgress_Adapter( Context ctx, List<Data_Inprogress> modelRecyclerArrayList) {
        this.inflater = inflater.from(ctx);
        this.modelRecyclerArrayList = modelRecyclerArrayList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public InProgressViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.in_progress_adapter, viewGroup, false);
        InProgressViewHolder holder = new InProgressViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InProgressViewHolder holder, int i) {
        for (i=0;i<modelRecyclerArrayList.size();i++){
            holder.location1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getLocaion());
            holder.date1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDate());
            holder.duration1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDuration());
            holder.username1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getUser_name());
            holder.workerid1.setText(String.valueOf(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getWork_order_id()));
            holder.description1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDescription());
            holder.useraddress1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getUser_address());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelRecyclerArrayList.size();
    }

    public class InProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          TextView location1,date1,username1,duration1,workerid1,description1,useraddress1
                ,tvorderid,tvdesc,tvusername,tvdate,tvlocation,tvdur,tvaddre,tvpay,tvamt,tvdt,tvcash,tvbal;
        public InProgressViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"fonts/Uber Move Text.ttf");
            location1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.location1);
            date1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.date1);
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
 private void fetchInPro() {
        RetrofitInterface jsonPostService = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitInterface.class, "http://littletreasure.org.in/");
        Call<InProgress_Response> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON1();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<InProgress_Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<InProgress_Response> call, Response<InProgress_Response> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    proDialog.cancel();
                    List<Data_Inprogress> datumList1 = response.body().getData();
                    /*for (int i = 0; i < datumList.size(); i++) {
                        datumList.add(response.body().getData().get(i));
                    }*/
                    if (getActivity()!=null){
                        proDialog.cancel();
                        inProgress_adapter = new InProgress_Adapter(getContext(),datumList1);
                        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        //recyclerView.notify();
                        recyclerView1.setAdapter(inProgress_adapter);
                    }



                }
            }
```

**This is my response**

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "10 results found.",
  "data": [
    {
      "work_order_id": 1,
      "description": "Desc-1",
      "locaion": "Locaion-1",
      "date": "0-01-2020",
      "duration": "1 days",
      "user_name": "User name-1",
      "user_address": "User address-1",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 0,
          "date": "0-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 2,
      "description": "Desc-2",
      "locaion": "Locaion-2",
      "date": "1-01-2020",
      "duration": "2 days",
      "user_name": "User name-2",
      "user_address": "User address-2",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 1,
          "date": "1-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 3,
      "description": "Desc-3",
      "locaion": "Locaion-3",
      "date": "2-01-2020",
      "duration": "3 days",
      "user_name": "User name-3",
      "user_address": "User address-3",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 2,
          "date": "2-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 4,
      "description": "Desc-4",
      "locaion": "Locaion-4",
      "date": "3-01-2020",
      "duration": "4 days",
      "user_name": "User name-4",
      "user_address": "User address-4",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 3,
          "date": "3-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 5,
      "description": "Desc-5",
      "locaion": "Locaion-5",
      "date": "4-01-2020",
      "duration": "5 days",
      "user_name": "User name-5",
      "user_address": "User address-5",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 4,
          "date": "4-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 6,
      "description": "Desc-6",
      "locaion": "Locaion-6",
      "date": "5-01-2020",
      "duration": "6 days",
      "user_name": "User name-6",
      "user_address": "User address-6",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 5,
          "date": "5-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 7,
      "description": "Desc-7",
      "locaion": "Locaion-7",
      "date": "6-01-2020",
      "duration": "7 days",
      "user_name": "User name-7",
      "user_address": "User address-7",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 6,
          "date": "6-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**this is my InProgress_Response**

```
public class InProgress_Response {
    private String status;
    private String message;
    /*data list of response*/
    private List<Data_Inprogress> data=null;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Data_Inprogress> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data_Inprogress> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**this is my Data_Inprogress**

```
public class Data_Inprogress {
    private  String description;
    private Integer work_order_id;
    private  String locaion;
    private  String date;
    private  String duration;
    private  String user_name;
    private  String user_address;
    @SerializedName("payment_details")
    @Expose
    private List<Payment_Inprogress> paymentDetails=null;

    public List<Payment_Inprogress> getPaymentDetails() {
        return paymentDetails;
    }

    public void setPaymentDetails(List<Payment_Inprogress> paymentDetails) {
        this.paymentDetails = paymentDetails;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getWork_order_id() {
        return work_order_id;
    }

    public void setWork_order_id(int work_order_id) {
        this.work_order_id = work_order_id;
    }

    public String getLocaion() {
        return locaion;
    }

    public void setLocaion(String locaion) {
        this.locaion = locaion;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getUser_address() {
        return user_address;
    }

    public void setUser_address(String user_address) {
        this.user_address = user_address;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your `InProgress_Response.class`

Comment: Can you add `InProgress_Response` and `Data_Inprogress` model?

Comment: please look once again above. i have added InProgress_Response class and Data_InProgress class model.

Comment: Why there is for loop inside onBindViewHolder?

Comment: i just tried to solve this issue but i am unable to solve it.

Comment: that's why i am asking you people because i am new in retrofit and i am unable to find solution please help me how can i solve this.

Comment: Can you Add Payment_Inprogress model?

Comment: Try using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert your JSON to POJO Classes. Maybe this would be helpful.

Comment: @ashwini violet i removed loop after that what should i do now?

Comment: @Ashwini Violet Thankyou so much for your effort this is helpfull and worked perfectly .you saved my life dear. thankyou once again :)

Comment: welcome! @vickeyrajak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can Access the values like

```
  @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InProgressViewHolder holder, int i) {

                holder.location1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getLocaion());
                holder.date1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDate());
                holder.duration1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDuration());
                holder.username1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getUser_name());
                holder.workerid1.setText(String.valueOf(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getWork_order_id()));
                holder.description1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getDescription());
                holder.useraddress1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getUser_address());

                // here how you access the values, here method name is based on convention, change with your get method name if different 
                holder.tvamt.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getPaymentDetails().get(0).getAmount());
                holder.tvdt.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getPaymentDetails().get(0).getDate());
                holder.tvcash.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getPaymentDetails().get(0).getPaymentMethod());
                holder.tvbal.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getPaymentDetails().get(0).getBalance());



        }
```

here is assumed your array of payment details have just one object (as you showed us in response)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Data_Inprogress model

```
 public class Data_Inprogress {
    private  String description;
    private Integer work_order_id;
    private  String locaion;
    private  String date;
    private  String duration;
    private  String user_name;
    private  String user_address;

    private List <Data_Inprogress> payment_details;

    private double amount;
    private String date;
    private String payment_method;
    private double balance;
    //create setter, getter
}
```

add this in your activity method

```
 private void fetchInPro() {
    RetrofitInterface jsonPostService = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitInterface.class, "http://littletreasure.org.in/");
    Call<InProgress_Response> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON1();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<InProgress_Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InProgress_Response> call, Response<InProgress_Response> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                proDialog.cancel();
                List<Data_Inprogress> datumList1 = response.body();
                /*for (int i = 0; i < datumList.size(); i++) {
                    datumList.add(response.body().getData().get(i));
                }*/

                /*----------------add this line ---------------*/

                 List<Data_Inprogress> paymentDtlLst = datumList1.getPayment_details();
                 //access nested array
                 for(Data_Inprogress payDtl : paymentDtlLst){

                    double amount=payDtl.getAmount();
                     String date=payDtl.getDate();
                     String payment_method= payDtl.getPayment_method();
                     double balance=payDtl.getBalance();
                    // Log.d("payment_details", data+payment_method);

                 }
                /*----------------end---------------*/
                if (getActivity()!=null){
                    proDialog.cancel();
                    inProgress_adapter = new InProgress_Adapter(getContext(),datumList1);
                    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    //recyclerView.notify();
                    recyclerView1.setAdapter(inProgress_adapter);
                }



            }
        }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: i just tried your code and its worked thank you so much for that. :)